# How array set in email.html file

Tags: template, custom, mail

i make custom mail template.
my template variables are `$TemplateParameter=[
           'customerName'=>$getOrderParams['customerName'],
           'orderItems'=>$getOrderParams['productinfo']
         ];`

and my 'html' file code is

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- pathe of template header-->

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans " Hello <b>%customerName</b>," customerName=$customerName|row}}</p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>

            <table class="email-items">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="item-info">{{trans "Item"}}</th>
                    <th class="item-info">{{trans "Sku"}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    // want to set Items and Sku here
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Can anyone tell me please how set `orderItems` array set in `table` body .

I received  mail correctly but now want to set content . 
[image]

Plz guide me how set Items and Sku in the mail content ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- pathe of template header-->

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans " Hello <b>%customerName</b>," customerName=$customerName|row}}</p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>

            <table class="email-items">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="item-info">{{trans "Item"}}</th>
                    <th class="item-info">{{trans "Sku"}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{layout handle="your_layout_file_name" items=$items area="frontend"}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**/app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/your_layout_file_name.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="email_name" template="Vendor_Module::email/items.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **/app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/template/email/items.phtml**

**In items.phtml you can get the data like customer name and order item**

Comment: how can get orderitems in `items.phtml` file ?

Comment: in this file you can call your clock file and get the data

Comment: Actually me data array is not in block file . i make observer `Vendor\module\Observer\filename.php`  in this file i call the mail method and send orderitems array in this file. how can get this array in .phtml file

Comment: send custom email ???

Comment: Yes! check i put mail screenshot in question

Comment: using transport bilder you send email ??

Comment: yes !
I need array set in  `Vendor\Module\Observer\file.php` and want to get here `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\template\email\file.phtml` in this file